# check if the user is a fan of my Facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook php SDK to login the user to the website. Also I am asking the user for permissions such as:

```
user_likes,publish_actions,email,offline_access,user_birthday
```

Now I am checking if the user is fan of my facebook page or not.

```
$isFan = $facebook->api(array(
            "method"    => "pages.isFan",
            "page_id"   => 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
            ));
```

The problem is when the user's Facebook session is over the above code is returning false even if the user liked the page before. Now is there any way to check if the liked my fan page with an access token for example. Since I am using offline access I have a valid user access token for 60 days then I will ask him to login again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run an [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) query on the [page_fan](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/) table.

```
$isFan = $facebook->api(array(
  "method" => "fql.query",
  "query"  => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = '<YOUR PAGE ID>' AND uid = '<UID>"
));
```

Also useful – http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Comment: This is only correct assuming you have the user_likes permissions and the user is authenticated.